# RedHat Enterprise 6 and Windows  7 dual boot

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have currently Windows 7 running and installed on partition C.
I have partition D empty , and I would like to install Red Hat on it without affecting Windows seven ( i.e.,  dual boot Windows 7 & Red Hat6 ).

Can any one please guide me how to do so?
I

Comment: I know this covers Ubuntu but it is basically the same process: http://superuser.com/questions/786/how-to-dual-boot-home-pc-with-linux-and-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you installed windows, you must have left some free space on your hard drive for the RHEL 5 installation.

burn the image to the usb drive, boot from it, install graphically, install grub as bootloader and TO THE MBR

Now, fdisk -l to list the paritions check and look up the parition for example /dev/sda2 where windows is installed as ntfs.
open up a terminal and edit with `vi /boot/grub/menu.lst` and add the following corresponding to your windows parition.

```
(0) YOUR RHEL entry
(1) Windows
title Windows 7
rootnoverify (hd0,1) (you might ask why (0,1) well for sda1 it would be (0,0) and sda2 (0,1) and so on...)
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

reboot and you should be able to boot both into rhel and windows

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot from your Linux CD, and during the installation process, choose the correct partition to install Linux on. From there, the Linux installation process should automatically configure a boot loader for dual boot.

It's entirely possible that some step of this process won't be automatic, and the biggest risk you run is having the installer delete your Windows partitions. Ideally, with dual boot, you would have a separate hard drive to install on, and could disconnect your Windows drive to protect it. From there you could boot from the BIOS quick select (usually the Esc key).

All that said, I suggest setting up a VM product like VirtualBox or VMWare Player, and seeing if running RHEL6 in a VM meets your needs. If it does, you're all set, and can work in both OSes side by side. If you still need to install RHEL to the hard drive for performance reasons, you'll at least have a better idea of what to expect from setting up the VM.

Answer (score 0):

This grub.conf worked with a workstation with EFI with 2 disks, sda, sdb
Red Hat Enterprise 6.6 was installed at sda

```
sda1 /boot/efi
sda2 swap
sda3 /
```

Windows 10 pro was installed at sdb

```
sdb1 a Microsoft reserved partition with 16 MB
sdb2 ntfs for Windows 10
```

at /etc/grub.conf or /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.conf
the top section was auto created by anaconda, the Windows 10 had to be remade

the UUID for Windows 10 section was copied from the anaconda's one
so keep every thing from top to initrd line

```
device (hd0) HD(1,800,100000,314d5444-d170-4e02-95a4-b388331857bb)
default=0
timeout=120
splashimage=(hd0,2)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6 (2.6.32-504.30.3)
root (hd0,2)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=49b8182c-cc3c-47e4-a960-3e4d91ceb0c6 nomodeset rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=pt-latin1 rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet crashkernel=auto
initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64.img

title Windows 10 Professional EN - boot manager
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
insmod search_fs_uuid
insmod chain
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1 49b8182c-cc3c-47e4-a960-3e4d91ceb0c6
else
  search --fs-uuid --set=root 49b8182c-cc3c-47e4-a960-3e4d91ceb0c6
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

please notice when installing Linux after Windows to include de /boot/efi partition but not to format it.

on a 1 disk system already with Windows 10 OEM the ESP partition (EFI) is the 2nd one so the root line should be:

```
set root='hd0,gpt2'
```

this case was for a legacy situation with GRUB v.1 bual boot;

Linux CentOS 7 / Red Hat 7 deals ok with dual-booting with GRUB 2

Answer (score -1):

You said that you're currently running Windows 7 and have it installed on partition C. Partition D is empty, and you want to install RHEL6 on it without affecting Windows 7 (i.e., dual booting Windows 7 & Red Hat6).

First of all, log into Windows 7 and remove the `D` partition from disk management. Go to the *run* dialog box and type `diskmgmt.msc`.

Now, check free space. You can use the shrink option in Windows 7 to decrease your main partition (the C drive). Right-click on the C, then shrink the volume. After that you have to restart your system because you changed your main partition configuration.

Then, boot from the RHEL6 DVD and install RHEL6 normally. Now during the installation, when RHEL6 asks for type of installation, choose *create custom layout*.

My partiton layout is:

> #### Windows
>
> - C partition is 28 GB
> - D partition is 128 GB
>
> #### Linux
>
> - `/` partition is 26 GB
> - `/boot` partition is 500 MB
> - `/home` partition is 16 GB
> - `/tmp` partition is 4 GB
> - `/usr` partition is 6 GB
> - `/var` partition is 14 GB
> - `/usr/local` partition is 4.5 GB
> - `/opt` partition is 11 GB
> - `swap` partition is twice the size as your RAM
> - `/yoo` partition is 16 GB, `vfat` filesystem

If you're using two HDDs, then the installation is different, so I recommend you to install on one HDD only.

Comment: This is an extremely odd partition setup. You've got too many partitions in there IMHO, and I have no idea what `/yoo` is for.